# Exporting related data to XML from Microsoft Access

Tags: xml, ms-access, export, relationship

I have a MS Access Database which a client has provided me with. I need to export data from it to XML for import into a Content Management System. Some of the rows in the primary table in Access have multiple child rows in another table. I want to export these child rows as nodes in my XML file, for example:

```
<entry>
    <title>XML Test Entry - Alpha</title>
    <author>email@example.com</author>
    <body>Body Text</body>
    <categories>
        <category>One</category>
        <category>Two</category>
    </categories>
    <tags>cheese,rainbows</tags>
    <status>open</status>
</entry>
```

However I'm a bit of a noob with Access so although I can generate output similar to the above with a single related row from the table in question I have no idea how to form a query to return multiples.

I am using the XML export wizard to create my SQL but I am reasonably familiar with MySQL so I would be comfortable editing the results SQL query.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `ExportXML`?

The following is from the Access 2010 help:

```
Sub ExportCustomerOrderData()
    Dim objOrderInfo As AdditionalData
    Dim objOrderDetailsInfo As AdditionalData

    Set objOrderInfo = Application.CreateAdditionalData

    ' Add the Orders and Order Details tables to the data to be exported.
    Set objOrderDetailsInfo = objOrderInfo.Add("Orders")
    objOrderDetailsInfo.Add "Order Details"

    ' Export the contents of the Customers table. The Orders and Order
    ' Details tables will be included in the XML file.
    Application.ExportXML ObjectType:=acExportTable, DataSource:="Customers", _
                          DataTarget:="Customer Orders.xml", _
                          AdditionalData:=objOrderInfo
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm not really familiar enough with Access to know where I might paste this... I've been using the SQL query view.

Comment: The above code is VBA, which goes in the VBA editor (press Alt+F11 to show). Generate a form with a button, and find the OnClick_Event in the properties (F4). Then copy the above code to the OnClick_Event.